# Yii CLinkPager & urlManager rules

Tags: yii, pagination, yii-url-manager

I have the following issue:

When I press a button in my pagination, CLinkPager generates the link as follows:

```
page/videos/445/?page=2
```

1. What I need is something like this:

   page/videos/445/page/2
2. Furthermore, I need something like:

   name/videos/2

where name is url of user_id = 445.

I've set some rules in urlManager but they don't quite do the job:
For step 1:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<page:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here example for page/videos/445/page/2.This will help you understand:

```
//config
'rules'=>array(
            'page/videos/<number:\d+>/page/<pageId:\d+>' => '/site/test',
             ...

//...SiteController...
//url for call www.your_site.lh/page/videos/445/page/2
public function actionTest($number, $pageId)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_GET);
    echo "$number<br/>";
    echo "$pageId<br/>";
    echo '</pre>';
    die();
}
```

[URL Management](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url)

If you want to change generation links in pager you can override CLinkPager.